# How to change this code to polars ?" TypeError: 'GroupBy' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python, pandas, python-polars

This code is pandas.

```
pandas_reserve_tb \
        .groupby(['hotel_id', 'people_num'])['total_price'] \
        .sum().reset_index()
```

I would like to change this code to polars.

```
polars_researve_tb \
        .groupby("hotel_id", "people_num")['total_price'] \
        .sum().with_row_count()
```

But, I got the error

> "TypeError: 'GroupBy' object is not subscriptable"

How to solove this error?

Comment: It looks like you want `.agg()` e.g. `.groupby().agg(pl.col("total_price").sum())` - an example dataframe would help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably meant

```py
polars_researve_tb \
        .groupby(["hotel_id", "people_num"]).agg(pl.col('total_price').sum())
```

I'd advise posting reproducible examples in the future